# Race For Wool Gaming.SE map

Tags: discussion, game-on, minecraft

> ### Edit
>
> We'll finally, hopefully be playing this map on **Sunday the 15th of April**

For those of you paying attention in chat over the past few days, you'll know I've made a Race For Wool Minecraft map, with help from RonanForman and JohnTheGreen:

[image]

It's an adventure-style map, no block breaking etc. It's designed for two teams of two, but the number of people per team could be increased if there's a lot of interest.

If you'd like to play, leave an answer.

If you'd be interested in helping filming, please mention that too!

Comment: @JeffreyLin Pretty sure you can get it from the YouTube page...

Answer (score 1):

I would like to partake in playing. I would need to check with any scheduling conflicts but 4PM EST should be fine for me :)

Comment: Ping! Still interested in playing? Speak to me in chat so we can sort teams.

Answer (score 1):

I'm up for it, and generally anytime that weekend would be fine.

Comment: Ping! Still interested in playing? Speak to me in chat so we can sort teams.

Comment: @fredley - I ended up having to leave town at the last minute, actually. ;_;

Answer (score 1):

***Count me in and filming!***

Comment: (I had to add the 6 asterisks to reach the 30 character limit.)

Answer (score 0):

I definitely want to play this.  Sunday the 4th around 9-10 UTC should work for me.

Comment: Noted, but people who didn't help build a lot of the traps get priority :-P

Comment: I'll try to be there. SOMEONE BUT UP A STEAM REMINDER!

Comment: @Fredy Only the mods can do that.

Comment: Exactly why I did ask that.

Comment: Ping! Still interested in playing? Speak to me in chat so we can sort teams.

Answer (score 0):

I'm interested in doing this. I've done a lot of pvp before.